# Command to open another instance of integrated terminal on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: bash, shell, npm, command-line, visual-studio-code

This question is specifically for Visual Studio Code (VS Code) and it's integrated terminal.

Is it possible to open another integrated terminal to run certain commands from npm scripts or from within one terminal?

For example: if the command "Start cmd" is executed, it opens a new separate window. But, is it possible to force that command to open and run inside another integrated terminal within VS Code?

Note:
There are keyboard shortcuts avaiable to open, close, show, hide etc, but this question is asking about performing these actions from code or command not using keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You can open multiple IT in VSC: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio code has nice keyboard shortcuts for opening new integrated terminal instances:

For Windows:

```
Ctrl+Shift+`
```

For Macintosh

```
Ctrl+Shift+~
```

For more information on shortcuts take a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) for Windows and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/keyboard-shortcuts?view=vsmac-2019) for Macintosh. At least this way you can run any command you want in multiple instances. For example, run your server in one integrated window, and other one off commands in another instance, etc...

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It should be clear from the example provided in the question. How can you run any command for example: `START CMD` and have it open in another integrated terminal. Or how can you set the npm script commands to automatically open in different multiple integrated terminals. Just like in regular command prompt if you run `start [any_command]`, it opens that command in another window. This question is looking for a way to achieve similar behavior with multiple integrated terminals.

Comment: I see now, to be fair I read it originally as: "How can I open another integrated terminal to run an npm script cmd?" I don't think I was the only one who misinterpreted it this way either. Your last edit makes the question clearer